# Use map() function with string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, lambda

Is there a way to use `map()` function with a string instead of a list? Or the `map()` function is meant only to work with lists?

For instance, ignoring the content of the lambda function, this code returns a map object and not a string:

```
def rot_13(string):
    alph = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz'
    return str(map(lambda i: alph[(alph.find(i)+13) % len(alph)], string))
```

Comment: `map` returns a generator in Python3, try: `return "".join(list(map(lambda i: alph[(alph.find(i)+13) % len(alph)], string)))`

Comment: You can turn a string into a list with something like `a_list = list(a_string)`.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer map returns a map object, not a generator

Comment: Yes. `map` **always** returns a map object. No matter the iterable you are napping over. It is meant to work with any iterable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using list/generator comprehensions is preferable (more Pythonic) to `map()`:

```
def rot_13(string):
    alph = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz'
    return ''.join(alph[(alph.find(i)+13) % len(alph)] for i in string)
```

Answer (score 6):

python3 `map` returns a generator, so you have to consume it, using [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) is the easiest way:

```
"".join(map(lambda i: alph[(alph.find(i)+13) % len(alph)], string))
```

It is similar to this code:

```
my_string = ""
for l in map(lambda i: alph[(alph.find(i)+13) % len(alph)], string):
    my_string += l
```

Comment: `map` does not return a generator, it returns a map-object, which is an iterator but not a generator.